# Why does IntelliJ generate different import statements for .spec files?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea

I wonder why the IntelliJ `Add import statement` works differently when used in a spec file:

The setup is very simple.
In the project `tsconfig.base.ts` file we specify a path:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "paths": {
      "@idea-import-spec/data": [ "libs/data/src/index.ts" ]
    }
  },
```

In the same `lib` directory we have 3 files:

`util.ts` exports a constant:

```
export const TEST = 1;
```

and 2 files that import this constant.
e.g. in `data.ts`

- add `const x = TEST;`
- then move the cursor to the end of `TEST`
- press ALT+ENTER and select `Add import statement`
- this will add a relative import - which is okay and expected:

```
import {TEST} from "./util";
```

But when I do the same in the file `data.spec.ts`, it uses the path import!

```
import {TEST} from "@idea-import-spec/data";
```

**Why is this different and how to fix it?**

More details:

- Here is the full [GitHub test-repository](https://github.com/tmtron/idea-import-spec-plain)
- I have even changed both `tsconfig.lib.json` and `tsconfig.spec.json` to have the same contents
- IntelliJ Version: 2021.1.2 Ultimate
- Screenshot of the issue:
  [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **Use path mappings from tsconfig.json** set to **Always**, the IDE tries to use the mappings any time the import is added. But, as `"@idea-import-spec/data"` is mapped to `libs/data/src/index.ts` that, in turn, re-exports everything from `lib/data.ts`, adding a mapped import to `data.ts` would result in a circular dependency - that's why a relative path is used. But `data.spec.ts` is not re-exported in barrel, so using a path mappings there looks safe

Comment: Thanks  that sounds reasonable.  
But, I have `Use path mappings from tsconfig.json` set to `Only in files outside specific paths`, so shouldn't IntelliJ always use the relative path in this case (i.e. in the ts and in the spec.ts file)?

Comment: it you change the mappings to `"@idea-import-spec/data/*": ["libs/data/*"]`, it will work this way; but your mappings are not a path mapping but a file alias

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot change this, as it is enforced by [nrwl-nx](https://nx.dev/)

Comment: thanking the lord i found this question and this answer !